# How to limit number of element per page using jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

i need to know if exist a jquery's plugin to limit the number of element in a page and showing the little number in the bottom of the page to show the other elements. Does someone know some plugins that do this? Thanks!!+

This is an example:

[image: Example]

Comment: what elements? are you talking abt html controls?

Comment: What do you mean by "limit"? It seems that you are looking for something like twitter's timeline, but I'm not sure.

Comment: See edit.. i added an image to show the numbers in the bottom of page to "show" other elements

Comment: Search google for "pagination" plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "pagination". You will find tons of jQuery Plugins for that purpose.

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

compares 10 plugins, see if one of those fits your needs.

Note however, that a real pagination should be done serverside, as a clientside pagination still has all the elements present, which at very large numbers can lead to performance-problems.